# Why are sealed classes not allowed to be mocked?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, unit-testing, inheritance, mocking

Using Moq framework, it is not allowed to mock a class in C# which is sealed. Same goes for many other frameworks as well. But why is it not allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mocking a class usually works by using reflection to construct a subclass which has methods and properties that do nothing (or whatever is required for the mock).

"Sealed" classes cannot be subclassed, so they cannot be mocked. If you have a sealed class X, then *only* instances of X will satisfy the typechecker for function parameters which require X.

Three solutions:

- make an *interface*, which the sealed class implements, and make functions take the interface. They can then accept mock objects as well. You do then lose some of the optimizer benefits of sealed.
- unseal the class
- use real objects rather than mocks, which is easier if they don't have too much behavior.

Comment: Good answer. Still I think *"don't have too much behavior."* is not the right criterion. A better criterion is *"Can be constructed and initialized easily"* (in memory, without using an external service or the need of creating tons of helper objects first).

Comment: IOW, it has nothing to do with it "not being allowed". It is simply not possible.

Comment: I also found a useful link which explains an alternate approach while dealing with mocking of sealed or static classes.
https://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MockSealedStatic.aspx

Comment: @JörgWMittag or "not allowed" by a language rule, rather than "not allowed" by a library-writer decision